# Pointer not pointing to the correct array element after function call

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I have two pointer variables in my main function: largest_ptr and smallest_ptr.
The task is to call the find_max_min() function to assign the largest and smallest elements within two arrays (both global) to the respective pointers.

```
void find_min_max(uint8_t* a, uint8_t* b); //function declaration

uint8_t array1[] = { <some values> };  
uint8_t array2[] = { <some values> };  

int main(void)
{
  uint8_t* largest_ptr;
  uint8_t* smallest_ptr;
  find_min_max(largest_ptr, smallest_ptr); //this does not assign any addresses

}

void find_min_max(uint8_t* largest, uint8_t* smallest){
   //correct code to find the max/min in array1 and array2, and assign the addresses of the elements to largest and smallest
}
```

I tried debugging my find_min_max function, and the result was correct i.e the correct values were assigned to the largest and smallest pointers. However, when I call the function in main(), the respective addresses are not assigned to largest_ptr and smallest_ptr. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

P.S
My apologies for not posting the code. This is an assignment question, and this may get detected in the plagiarism test. I am confident this is enough to explain my situation

Comment: Are you changing `largest` and `smallest` directly in the function ( e.g.: `largest = array1[0];`)? if yes then you probably should declare the function as `void find_min_max(uint8_t** a, uint8_t** b);`

Comment: use double pointer. E.g `void find_min_max(uint8_t** largest, uint8_t** smallest){` and call `find_min_max(&largest_ptr, &smallest_ptr); `

Comment: Read what "pass by value" means! Note: C is **strictly** pass by value. There is absolutely no call-by-reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**smallest_ptr** is a variable of type pointer to uint_8, and a value that it holds is an address. Function definition you've created declares **smallest** as another such pointer. When You perform a function call, You initialize **smallest** with result of evaluation of expression. Often such expression is literal or single variable. Latter is the case here. Expression **smallest_ptr** evaluates to certain address, which is passed by value to function, that is - is assigned to **smallest**.

Although I can't see the inner workings of your function, I assume You do not read from **smallest**, but write to it. However **smallest** is a local variable with scope and lifetime tied to the function. You write to this variable and then the result is lost.

What You're trying to achieve is manipulate some data outside of your function scope. One of the possibilities is to provide address of that data to the function via argument, declared like this:

```
func( TYPE* x)
{
    //...
    *x = VALUE; // we don't want to set local variable, 
    // but the variable being pointed to by it, so we dereference the local pointer
}
```

Invoked like this:

```
TYPE y;
func(&y);
```

Where & is address operator, so we provide address of y for the func() function to be able to write into.

Since in your case variable that needs to be manipulated is pointer to uint8_t, You need to pass address of a pointer, so a local variable needs to be a pointer to a pointer - func(int** x);

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. My method declaration is now: `void find_min_max(uint8_t** a, uint8_t** b);`. I pass the address of largest_ptr and smallest_ptr as arguments into the function. However, there is another problem that I can't manage to fix (sorry, I am a newbie at this). In my `find_min_max()` function, I call two other functions with declaration: `uint8_t* find_min(uint8_t* array_ptr, uint8_t len)` and a similar `find_max` function.

Comment: So how do I assign the local variable `smallest` in the `find_min_max()` function to the value returned by 'find_min()' (which is a pointer). I have tried this assignment: `smallest_ptr = &(find_min(array1, array1_len))`. But the compiler gives me an error: `lvalue required as unary '&' operand`. I would really appreciate your help again.

Comment: Please read sections: Dereference and Address of, http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access

Comment: What You need is good understanding of that, and a follow up analysis of interaction between a function being called and the function calling it. Their communication is limited to several channels. One of those is through globals, which i would advise to avoid. Whenever You feel compelled to use globals as a means to carry data between scopes of program (fe. between two independent functions), do try to avoid that by using other channels.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your pointer parameters through their adress in order to achieve your goal.

```
void find_min_max(uint8_t** a, uint8_t** b);

find_min_max(&largest_ptr, &smallest_ptr);
```

instead of

```
void find_min_max(uint8_t* a, uint8_t* b);
```